How to configure GitHub Actions to trigger create and push events exclusively for branch creation and future updates?
I have this condition on my workflow:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
  create:
    branches:
      - 'release/[0-9]+.[0-9]+'

When I create a branch named something like release/1.2 I want only one pipeline triggered with create event, and future pushes to this branch will trigger with push.
Basically push and create should be exclusive like so:




event_name=create workflow
event_name=push workflow




Branch created
V
X


Push to existing branch
X
V



I do not want to put conditions on jobs, I need the workflow to not even start.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

I ended up having only "push" event
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

And whenever I need to know if it is a branch creation within my pipeline I use github.event.created from the context.
For example here is a custom title for each scenario:
run-name: >
  ${{ 
  startsWith(github.ref_name, 'release/') && github.event.created && 'Create Release' ||
  startsWith(github.ref_name, 'release/') && 'Hotfix' ||
  'Push' 
  }}

First one is for release, second for Hotfix and third for push to any other branch.
